# Please tell me the rule in the Realtime database of Firebase that can be accessed only from the specified application installed from Google Play

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Please tell me the rules to prevent reading and writing in the Realtime database of Firebase from Other than 'specified application installed from Google Play' and my Firebase console.
Full access is fine as long as it is from the specified app.

Comment: It's not possible.  You can only limit access to authenticated users within your project.

Comment: There is only one app in the project. I want to prevent access from other than that app.

Comment: It's not possible.  Anyone with an internet connection can read and write your database unless you restrict access to Firebase Auth users.  Read the marked duplicate.

Comment: Does restricting access to Firebase Auth users mean restricting access to regular users?

Comment: Firebase Auth is being accessed by a large number of unfamiliar users. No one has downloaded the app! How did they access it?

Comment: If you have new questions, please post them separately.